# How to get the live streaming log in the Consumer and store into the Cassandra?

Tags: apache-kafka

Want to get streaming logs via consumer and then stored it into a Cassandra by (Kafka connect Cassandra or kafka-connect-cassandra-sink) without script

I referred `https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-cassandra-sink-the-perfect-match/` link but not found proper solution.

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify what you mean by " but not get proper result" ?